# HLS Sampler Plugin

Tags: jmeter-plugins

I'm exploring the HLS sampler plugin and have a .m3u8 hls manifest file.I have enabled the below things in the sampler - 
Whole video
Min resolution available
Min bandwidth available.

URL - https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8 - This is a sample URL

On triggering the request,I'm getting -  Response message: Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue as it evidenced by the below snapshot:

[image: JMeter HLS Plugin Working Evidence]

So my expectation is that there is a kind of connectivity issue between JMeter and the application under test. Most likely you are sitting behind a corporate proxy or so, if this is the case - you need to "tell" JMeter its details like:

```
jmeter -H proxy-host -P proxy-port ....
```

See [Using JMeter behind a proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) User Manual chapter for more details. Just in case check out [The New HLS Plugin for JMeter - The Complete Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-hls-plugin-for-jmeter-the-complete-guide) for comprehensive information on using the plugin.